# sql query naming issue in concat

Tags: mysql

I am stuck in a very small issue in my sql query. One of my developers did some work for me and now i am unable to find him. The issue is quite small. I am just not sure what to put in it. i tried variations in the uery but still the output is not coming properly. here is the query

```
SELECT p.product_id,
            CONCAT(pd.name,' ',p.model) as product_model,       
            p.model, 
            p.price, 
            ocd.name AS category, 
            m.name AS brand, 
            CONCAT_WS('',CONCAT_WS('','http://www.sitename.com/index.php?route=product/product&modelnumber=',p.model),'&path=1&product_id=',p.product_id) AS productpageurl
            FROM oc_product p
            LEFT JOIN oc_manufacturer m ON m.manufacturer_id = p.manufacturer_id
            LEFT JOIN oc_product_to_category pc ON pc.product_id = p.product_id
            LEFT JOIN oc_product_description pd ON pd.product_id = p.product_id
            LEFT JOIN oc_category_description ocd ON ocd.category_id = pc.category_id
            LIMIT $index,10000
```

Now in this line

```
"CONCAT(pd.name,' ',p.model) as product_model,"
```

What i want is pd.name to be brand. The one below in this line

```
m.name AS brand,
```

it is showing correctly the brand name but not the one above. I am a total noob in sql so just want some help to finish this project. appreciate any help i could get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CONCAT(m.name,' ',p.model) as product_model,
```

Answer (score 0):

i didnt get what you want to happen in the database but if you want to change concat to brand

```
CONCAT(pd.name,' ',p.model) AS brand
```

or

```
pd.name AS brand
```